# Converting VarChar Column with multiple date format to single date column with proper format

Tags: sql, sql-update, alter

I have data of transaction dates in one column within varchar format.

[image: 1]

This column contains three separate formats of date in dd-mm-yy, dd/dd/yyyy and third format in dd/mm/yyy format with missing the last digit.

How to modify this column in the correct date format column with the dd-mm-yyyy format.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And for reference, the correct date format would be YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 1):

Add a date column and fill with your convert statement to get the desired format. Once everything looks okay you can drop the text column and rename the new proper date column to match the original.

Comment: Thanks for reverting, what if I only have read-only access, will this work even then, any way to do this with Update and Case statement?

Comment: you won't be able to change the schema with to be not varcahr with read-only access. You won't be able to use an update statement with read-only access.